# Retain original InfoPath submit date in form

Tags: submit, infopath

The form is submit to email. I want to get the date of the submit as a variable. Setting a variable with `now()` is not adequate as the variable changes when the form is opened again after submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

1. > Simply create a field in your form, set its default value to the
   >   `now()` function, and uncheck "Update this value when the result of
   >   the formula is recalculated." and you should be all set.

   via http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/12569/44295.aspx#44295
2. Create a variable `submissionDate` to store the submission date. When the user submits the form, set `submissionDate` to the current date. Add a check to only set the date if the variable does not already contain a value. If not implemented this exact way, this idea could be used in some form. I don't see why it wouldn't work.
3. Similar solution to #2 suggested here: [I need a submit date that doesn't change](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7189/26271.aspx#26271).

   > You just need to add a field to your form which saves the original
   >   file name.
   >
   > Have a rule on open which if filename is blank, sets is to your concat
   >   (addedtotable, ID).  Then in your SP submit use this field as the file
   >   name.
   >
   > On subsequent opens since it has a value the file name will not
   >   change.
   >
   > On your exisitng forms you will need to manually set this since you
   >   want to retain the original file name but on any new this solves your
   >   issue.
   >
   > Another option is to query the document library and maybe look for your
   >   user's name if you identify the user and the most recent file they
   >   have opened.
4. A few more suggestions here: [Submitting Infopath forms to a Sharepoint Library - how can I generate a unique name for each record](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/submitting-infopath-forms-sharepoint-136783.aspx).

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work if the user possibly saves the form and submits another day when finished filling it out. I'll hopefully be able to implement solution 2 if I can figure out how to both run some code at form submit time without losing capability to use the email submit connection. I'll be using a hidden date control. This way i'll get the submit date as part and parcel of all the answers in xml format. Thanks. Still don't have access to a sharepoint server, so can't do more elaborate things.

Comment: There should be no problem running code before submit [OnSubmitRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa662351(v=office.11).aspx) Also, #4 contains many solutions that center around your problem even though the title says Sharepoint. It's worth looking through.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JSuar for elaborating further. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Created a unique Form ID field based on the date/time using the now() function.  Problem was that ID changed, each time form was updated which presented a problem.

I am using InfoPath 2013.  To resolve the issue:

1. Select the Form Field for the ID.
2. Using Ribbon, click Control Properties.
3. Select Default Value or Field Properties, which brings up the Field or Group Properties window.
4. Uncheck "Refresh Value when formula is recalculated.
5. Click OK and republish the form.  Test and it works.